Configuring Delphi MVC Framework as DLL for Apache
I am having issues configuring my Delphi project as .dll library for Apache webserver.
I am using Delphi MVC Framework component for Delphi 12.0.
I am able to generate .dll and configure Apache to use it, but some reason I cannot properly define root path for my endpoints that would start as "/".
So I want to have: https://localhost:3030/login, but that doesn't work.
Here is my Apache httpd-ssl.conf, which doesn't work.
Listen 3030 
<VirtualHost localhost:3030> 
ServerName localhost:3030

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/conf/API_certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache24/conf/API_privateKey.key"

#LoadModule 
sql_api_apache_module modules/isql_api_apache.dll

#DMVCFRAMEWORK API 
<Location /> 
SetHandler isql_api_apache-handler
</Location>

ErrorLog "C:/Apache24/logs/error.log" 
CustomLog "C:/Apache24/logs/access.log" common

LogLevel debug   
</VirtualHost>

If I change
<Location /> 
SetHandler isql_api_apache-handler
</Location>

to
<Location /api> 
SetHandler isql_api_apache-handler
</Location>

that works and I am able to access https://localhost/api/login.
But it is not ideal since I do not wish there to be '/api'.
My snippet code of MyControllerU class, where I define my endpoints is this one:
unit MyControllerU;

interface

uses MVCFramework, MVCFramework.Commons, IB_Session, IB_Components, IB_Access, ActiveX, System.NetEncoding, DB;

type

  [MVCPath('/')]
  TMyController = class(TMVCController)
    function TextCislo(Text: string): Int64;
    function CisloCarka(Cislo: string): string;{převede číslo 1,50 na 1.50}
  public
    [MVCPath('/login')]
    [MVCHTTPMethod([httpPOST])]
    procedure DoLogin(ctx: TWebContext); 

Can anyone help?
Thank you.

doesn't work - could you add more details? What have you tried to test it?

Just browser and Postman, i needed to add SetHandler isql_api_apache-handler
for my .dll module api to be served. But when i set the parameter in  to be '/' since I don't want there to be anything added before my defined endpoints, i usually just get 404 error. I can only get my dll to work, if i either specify the location like /api, then it works at localhost:3030/api/login for example and If i ommit  and only have SetHandler isql_api_apache-handler, i can add anything before my endpoints like /tsdstdst/login and it will work, but just /login itself won't work.
